# How to set focus of ICEFaces component after initial rendering?

Tags: focus, icefaces

I have a complex ICEFaces XHTML page that renders certain components conditionally, based on flags set as the user enters data on the page. What I'd like to do is direct focus to a certain field as soon as it appears, which may not be during the initial render of the page.

The [ICEFaces documentation](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_8_2/tld/ice/outputBody.html) suggests that I can do this using the focus attribute of the outputBody component. Specifically:

> If you setting the initial focus, the focused component must be rendered on first render call, if not then set the focus attribute only when the component gets rendered.

This seems to suggest that I can manipulate the value of the focus attribute **at the time that my conditional component gets rendered.** However, I don't see any attributes of the inputText component that allow me to change a value at the time the component is rendered.

Am I misreading the documentation? When and where can I alter the value of the focus attribute of outputBody so that my conditionally-rendered field gets the input focus when it appears? Or am I using the wrong tool to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that I'm using both Seam and ICEFaces, I was not able to invoke Javascript reliably from my server-side Java code. I was, however, able to add the necessary Javascript in-line in my XHTML, within the ui:component that was being conditionally rendered, close to the input field I needed the focus to go to. The relevant section of my XHTML looks like this:

```
<ice:panelGroup id="textPanelInput" >
    <ice:form id="textInputForm"  partialSubmit="true" style="vertical-align:middle;">
        <ice:inputText id="textInput"  valueChangeListener="#{appField.valueChangeListener}"
                       size="#{appField.fieldDefLengthAsInt}" 
                       value="#{appField.value}"
                       styleClass="fieldStyle" rendered="#{appField!=null}"
                       >                    
        </ice:inputText>
        <ice:message id="jo" for="textInput" />
    </ice:form>
</ice:panelGroup>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('panelsFields:0:textInputForm:textInput').focus();</script>
```

The Javascript line at the bottom is the line I added to solve my problem. All of the code above is in a ui:component block that may or may not be rendered, based on other conditions. When this ui:component block is rendered, my Javascript goes with it, and sets the input focus to my desired input field.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this

```
JavascriptContext.applicationFocus(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "form:fieldM");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Javascript to set focus on an element.

Here's the Java snippet required to do this:

```
      JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
                    "document.getElementById('myForm:myTxtBox').focus();");
```

`myTxtBox` is the ID of your form element, and `myForm` is the ID of your form.

You can use this wherever you are changing certain variables' values to render/hide fields.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my testing, this method sometimes worked and sometimes did not, based on what action caused the system to render my page or to show my conditional field. I was able to verify that the addJavascriptCall() was always firing when I needed it to; however, the Javascript itself did not always seem to execute. It's possible that the Seam framework I'm using is complicating matters. The method shown in the accepted answer for this question appeared to work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

ICEfaces supports javascript api which has setting focus function. Thus you may use it like in  the next excerpt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      ice.applyFocus(elementId);
  });
</script>
```

`elementId` is `jsf component clientId`.

[ICEFaces javascript Api](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/JavaScript+Client+API)